# Why does Docker require udp ports to function - Can I disable this?

Tags: mac, docker, udp, pf

I came across strange behaviour with docker, where I tried to block all external UDP incoming & outgoing connections except for DNS (see mac pf config below) which breaks my docker containers.

Why does docker need UDP to function, and how can I disable this?

pf config:

```
block in proto udp all
block out proto udp all
pass in proto udp from {10.0.0.0/8 172.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 127.0.0.1} to any
pass out proto udp from {10.0.0.0/8 172.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 127.0.0.1} to any
pass out proto udp from any to any port 53
```

Comment: Do these rules operate on a first match wins? If so, you're blocking all UDP and your `pass` statements are never being tested.

Comment: In addition you would be allowing any communication from/to internal networks to any other network essentially the opposite of your block statements.

Comment: pf on mac operates on a last match wins, so should pass all the local traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Docker's system services are using UDP as can be seen from `lsof` output:

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 509 vagrant    5u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaecccc1      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:65346
com.docke 509 vagrant    7u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaecbe81      0t0  UDP *:61332
com.docke 511 vagrant   16u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaecdb01      0t0  UDP *:59414
com.docke 511 vagrant   17u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaecdd61      0t0  UDP *:58270
com.docke 511 vagrant   18u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaeca6c1      0t0  UDP *:49231
com.docke 511 vagrant   21u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaeccf21      0t0  UDP *:54016
com.docke 511 vagrant   22u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaecd181      0t0  UDP *:62272
com.docke 511 vagrant   23u  IPv4 0x8440b8fcdaecb501      0t0  UDP *:65286
```

As to your Pf's ruleset, I'd recommend using in the beginning of its filtering rules simple `pass quick on lo0`